# Angular ngModules import Error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I want to create a module related to the chart and write it elsewhere.

The source code of module declaration is as follows.


chart.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'

import { CLineChartComponent } from './cline-chart/cline-chart.component';
import { DoughnutChartComponent } from './doughnut-chart/doughnut-chart.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CLineChartComponent,
    DoughnutChartComponent    
  ],
  exports: [
    CLineChartComponent,
    DoughnutChartComponent
  ]
})
export class CustomChartModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CustomChartModule,
      providers: []
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to load it using another module forRoot function only.

The source for loading modules using forRoot function is:


dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { CustomChartModule } from '@Library/chart.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CustomChartModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class DashboardRootModule { }
```

However, when I use it like this, I get an error.

Error: Template parse errors: 'cline-chart' is not a known element:

I get an error when I try to use CLineChartComponent from a Component in the same directory as Dashboard.root.modules.

Why this error occur?

ps. i append clinechart.component.ts source.

The source is too long, so I deleted the part related to Option.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'cline-chart',
  templateUrl: './cline-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cline-chart.component.css'],
})
export class CLineChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showFlag(flag:boolean){
    this.isLoad = flag;
  }

  setCLineChartData(dataSet:Array<any>,legendName:string,titleName:string){
  //this funciton is Set Data
  }

  public width: number = 230;
  public heigth: number = 100;

  public lineChartOptions: any = {
  //this Object is Chart Option
  };
  public lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
  //this Array is Defined Line color
  ];
  // events
  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //Declare
  ],
  imports: [
    DashboardModule,
    //Import another
  ],
  providers: [
    //Porvider Anoter
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardRootComponent } from './dashboard-root/dashboard-root.component';
import { BapIframeModule } from './../shared/bap-iframe/bap-iframe.module';
import { DashboardRootModule } from './dashboard-root/dashboard-root.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DashboardRootModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),    
    BapIframeModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    DashboardRootComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DashboardComponent,
    DashboardRootComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

dashboard.root.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { GridPanelComponent } from './grid-panel.component/grid-panel.component'
import { GridScrollComponent } from './grid-scroll.component/grid-scroll.component'

import { CustomChartModule } from '@Libarary/chart.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CustomChartModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    GridPanelComponent,
    GridScrollComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    GridPanelComponent,
    GridScrollComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardRootModule { }
```

Comment: post your chart line component code

Comment: Ok Wait a Second

Comment: i add my cline component source

Comment: "Component in the same directory as Dashboard.modules" . What u mean by same directory? . The component in which you want to use `CLineChartComponent` should be added to the declarations array in `DashboardModule`;

Comment: that`s mean dashboard.root.component.ts. The module and the source code are written in the same folder.
There is a typo called dashboardModule. dashboardRootModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you trying to use the chart component? If it is added to a component from the DashboardModule then you should export the CustomChartModule from the DashboardRootModule:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  exports: [
    GridPanelComponent,
    GridScrollComponent,
    CustomChartModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class DashboardRootModule { }
```

If it is added to a component from the AppModule then you should also export the DashboardRootModule from the DashboardModule:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  exports: [
    DashboardComponent,
    DashboardRootComponent,
    DashboardRootModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

By the way the forRoot patterns makes sense only if you want to provide modules with and without providers.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I did not export the CustomChartModule to Dashboard.module, but it worked by exporting it to dashboard.root.module. 
I have a question. CustomChartModule is only used in DashBoard.Root.Module. But why would you put it in export?

Comment: Depends in which component are you using the chart components. If the root module export worked then I assume you are using them in the DashboardComponent or in the DashboardRootComponent. This angular documentation should clarify things up:
https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

Even thought **`CLineChartComponent`** resides within the **`CustomChartModule`** , you need to import the component in the module where you going to use it. So inside DashboardModule.ts

```
NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CustomChartModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
     CLineChartComponent
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But sadly, this method is also an error.  
It is said that ClineChartComponent is already defined in another module.

Comment: Type CLineChartComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: CustomChartModule and DashboardRootModule! Please consider moving CLineChartComponent to a higher module that imports CustomChartModule and DashboardRootModule.

Comment: What this error says is that I think ClineChart is defined by the parent module. However, defining all defines in the parent module will not require ChartMoudle.

Comment: There is one questionable part. ngmodule has three levels. AppModule imports the dashboard module. Again, the dashboard module imports the dashboardRoot module. It seems that this is a problem.

Comment: Sorry. I omitted the source code because it would be inconvenient if it was lengthened. First of all, I have added everything related to the module again. Thank you :)